# How do I calculate the number of times each line of code is executed?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have some pseudocode where I have to calculate the number of times the code is executed. The code is provided below.

```
    Historgram1(A,B,N)
    1     for k = 1 to N
    2          B[k] = 0
    3          for i = 1 to N
    4               if A[i] == k
    5               then B[k] = B[k] + 1
```

I know that line one would run n times but I am not sure about the others. I am also assuming that line 2 would run at least once since we are setting B[k] to a value of zero or would it be n + 1?

I am also unsure how to calculate th subsequent lines. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Big O doesn't deal in hard counts. It represents asymptotic behaviour. If you want to count, you add counter variables to the code.

Comment: Recommendation: answer the question, give your reasoning for your answers, and change the Question into "Am I right?" If we can see your process we can help you understand where it went wrong and help you to not fall into the same trap in the future. If someone just dumps the answer on you, you've got one answer and nothing more. Next time you get a question like this you'll be right back where you started.

Comment: You think Line 2 will be executed "at least once" and possibly `N+1` times. Why do you think it won't be executed "exactly `N` times"? It isn't dependent on the value that `B[k]` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, 1 and the whole loop body (2 to 5) are executed N times (for all values of k).

On every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop (3) is executed N times (for all values of i), as is line 4; but line 5 is executed conditionally, only if A[i]==k.

So far we can say:

- 1, 2: N times
- 3, 4: N² times.

Now line 5 is executed every time some A[i] equals some k in [1, N]. This may occur at most N times (once per A[i]), but might never occur, that's all we can say without knowing more about A.

The global behavior of the algorithm is O(N²), due to lines 3 and 4.

---

Anyway, the function name hints that we are computing an histogram, so it is likely that most of the values are in range [1,k] (unless the choice of the bins is very poor). So we can conjecture that line 5 is executed close to N times, without exceeding it.

This program uses a very poor method to compute the histogram, as this can be done in time O(N).